# Why jQuery page events not fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have the simple html with 2 JQM pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Test table</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(event, ui) {
            console.log('Whole document (+page 1) ready');
        });

        // Unreachable - doesn't matter which event is "on"
        $('#page_test2').on('pagecreate', function(event, ui) {
            console.log('Page 2 create event fired');
        });
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page_test1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#page_test2" data-role="button">Open next page</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page_test2">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Return to first page</a>
            <div id="place">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Found that page2 event handler not reached using "on".
What's wrong?
Here I found many long topics with very unclear answers.

Comment: AFAIK `pagecreate` will only fire on pages that are inserted into the DOM at runtime. If present in the markup you should probably use `pageinit`, see: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/ - also you need to use event delegation (`$(document).on('pageinit', '#sel',...`) as Schleis stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are registering the event, the `#page_test2` div doesn't exist.  You need to wrap the event registration in a `$(document).ready()` call so that you have all the DOM elements present when you set the event.

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#page_test2').on('pagecreate', function(event, ui) {
            console.log('Page 2 create event fired');
        });
});
```

You could also move the code to below the declaration of the div's that way they are present in the DOM when the javascript is executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Answers from Jozeidon and Scheis were very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Apply the event listener to the document:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page_test2', function() {
    //...
});
```